# How to get rid of white space in palindrome (Java)

Tags: java

```
public class reverserapp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please Enter a word");
      String str = scan.nextLine();

      String reverse = "";
      for( int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          reverse += str.charAt(i);

      if(reverse.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
          System.out.println("Palindrome");
      else System.out.println("Not Palindrome");

    }

}
```

This is my palindrome code. I'm doing this for a small assignment. I can get single words to work but if I write a something like "Don’t nod" it shows up as not palindrome. How can I achieve this? I'd like for my code to ignore punctuation's and white space.

So in the end result should be like "dontnod"

Thanks in advance for any help, complete noob at this.

Comment: What about filtering them out first?

Comment: use regex to remove all spaces and other characters like %$@$#^*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all non-letter characters, then put the resulting `String` to lower case .

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
str = str.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thanks bro! This worked. And thanks everyone for the quick replies, going to mess around with everyone else's code and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **replace** function from **StringUtils**.

Example:

```
StringUtils.replace("asdasd aaaa", " ", ""); //-> output: asdasdaaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `regex` to remove punctuation and space, and perform a String `replace` on input, e.g.:

```
String regex = "[\\p{Punct}\\s]";
String input = "don't nod";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```